# how to avoid the duplicate column values

Tags: mysql, oracle

Need to get those ids from the table below who dont have the time-in for november 2015

Table 1:

```
id_no        time-in 

S12      02-JUL-10 08.00.00
S12      07-OCT-10 10.00.00
S12      23-FEB-11 08.00.00
S12      01-FEB-14 09.00.00
S12      26-NOV-15 00.00.00
S68      15-MAR-06 08.00.00
S80      28-OCT-09 08.00.00
S80      07-OCT-10 10.00.00
S80      23-FEB-11 08.00.00
```

sample output

```
id_no 
s68
s80
```

I dont know how to write the query for the above. I tried with the below

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_NO FROM TABLE1
WHERE TO_CHAR(TIME_IN, 'YYYYMM') not in('201511');
```

I get the output as

```
id_no 
s12
s68
s80
```

I can understand that it take the repeated ids entries in the table. 
I need to avoid that.
Please help to write the query for getting the output as " sample output".

many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_NO FROM TABLE1 WHERE TO_CHAR(TIME_IN, 'YYYYMM') <> ('201511')
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT ID_NO FROM TABLE1 WHERE TO_CHAR(TIME_IN, 'YYYYMM') = '201511';
```

Above query will discard s12 as it has time in 2015 November.

Answer (score 0):

Your query selects the rows that aren't in November, and then displays the distinct `id_no`s they have. If you want to retrieve only the IDs that don't have an occurrence in November, the `exists` operator could help you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_no
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table1 t2
                   WHERE  TO_CHAR(t2.time_in, 'YYYYMM') = '201511' AND
                          t1.id_no = t2.id_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT statement you make is correct to prevent the duplicates. Personally I prefer using `GROUP BY`, but both are possible.

The to_char function I would not use for selecting on as the DB will have to apply this function to every record before it can start filtering. A range selection like `BETWEEN` or `>= AND <=` is usually much faster and clearer to read.

Two options:

1) Clean and simple: group by id_no, count all occurrences of site-in in November 2015 and only return the ones that have that count 0.

```
SELECT t1.id_no
FROM table1 AS t1
GROUP BY id_no
HAVING SUM(IF(t1.time-in BETWEEN '2015-11-01'AND '2015-12-01', 1, 0)) = 0;
```

2) With a sub query. I can imagine it would be easier for MySQL to successfully use the index with this. (Inspired by [Mureinik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34037868/3730184) answer):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id_no
FROM   table1 AS t1
WHERE  id_no NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id_no
    FROM   table1 AS t2
    WHERE  t2.time-in BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-12-01'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be7c4/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME AS
          SELECT 'S12' as id_no, DATE '2010-06-02' AS time_in
UNION ALL SELECT 'S12', DATE '2010-10-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 'S12', DATE '2011-02-23'
UNION ALL SELECT 'S12', DATE '2014-02-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 'S12', DATE '2015-11-26'
UNION ALL SELECT 'S68', DATE '2006-03-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'S80', DATE '2009-10-28'
UNION ALL SELECT 'S80', DATE '2010-10-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 'S80', DATE '2011-02-23';
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id_no
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id_no
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT( time_in, '%Y-%m-01' ) = DATE '2015-11-01' THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be7c4/6/0)**:

```
| id_no |
|-------|
|   S68 |
|   S80 |
```